# $P(N(2)=1, N(3)-N(1)=1)$

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a Poisson process $\{N(t),t\geq 0\}$ with intensity $\lambda=1/2$.

I want to calculate $P(N(2)=1\cap N(3)-N(1)=1)$. I know that $N(3)-N(1)$ and $N(2)$ are $Po(1)$ but they are not necessarily independent. So how can I calculate what event $N(2)=1\cap N(3)-N(1)=1$ represents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $N(t)$ denotes the number of points in interval $(0,t]$, then you can rewrite your original event in terms of independent events. Break up the interval $(0,3]$ into the three disjoint intervals $(0,1]$, $(1,2]$, and $(2,3]$ and consider what possibilities are equivalent to your original event. For example, one possibility is that there is one point in $(0,1]$, zero in $(1,2]$, and one point in $(2,3]$.

Comment: So would it be correct to split up my event to be $N(3)-N(2)=1 \cap N(2)-N(1)=0 \cap  N(1)=1 \ \text{or} \ N(3)-N(2)=0, N(2)-N(1)=1, N(1)=0$

Comment: Yes, those are the only two possibilities.